# First post appeared on the review queue long time after being asked

Tags: support, specific-question, review

This [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185169/inline-visitor-implementation-for-c11) was asked 12 hours ago. But it just appeared [a short moment ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/90309) on the review queue as a first post entry. How/why did this delay happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems like the question had been closed 2 minutes after being asked. It had then be reopened 21 minutes ago.

Check the timeline: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/185169/timeline

Comment: Exactly. This happens every so often, that we encounter a question in the Reopen queue before it's in the First Posts one. Often for precisely this reason.